# (when adding jar) - Module "android" must not contain source root

Tags: jar, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to add gdx-tools.jar to a libGDX project in IntelliJ. The result:

> Module "android" must not contain source root ".../android/src". The
>   root already belongs to module "android".

This is what I've tried:

project structure > libraries > new project library > java > select "gdx-tools.jar" >select module "desktop"

project structure > modules > select "desktop" > new > jars or directories > select "gdx-tools.jar" >

Ideas?

Answer (score 35):

Just by going to the Artifacts Settings, Modules, Sources tab, and you will see 2 folders called "gen" and "gen[generated]", delete "gen" by clicking on the X icon to the right of it.

look:
[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me, I have the same problem but there is only one gen folder

Comment: @elf_zwölf Same error message for me aswell, although had a duplicate src folder rather than gen

Comment: I opened from pom.xml again, and chose delete old project. Then reopened and it worked.

Comment: For me I added two folder is source folder - src/main and src/main/java. once i removed src/main from source folder I can run it easily.

Answer (score 10):

I had run into a similar issue as well:

> Module "(my_project)" must not contain source root "(my project)/src".
>   The root already belongs to module "(my_project)".

As I couldn't do anything on IDEA's configuration UI, I opened up the IDEA project file (**my_project.iml**) in vi, hoping to find out what's wrong:

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/my_project/src" type="java-resource" />
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/my_project/src" isTestSource="false" />
<!-- Duplicate entry found in project file -->
```

So eventually I solved my case by removing the duplicate entry manually.

As the IDEA project files were generated automatically from Gradle files, I have no idea what caused the duplicate entries to be created, but for those facing similar issues, a quick glance at the .iml file may help.

Comment: i hade the same issue,but in my case it was two iml files, one in .idea/modules and another in src/main, so I simply removed the iml file in src/main folder and the problem fixed.

Answer (score 9):

simple, just 'delete my_project.iml file and import project once again using File->New->Project From Existing Sources'

Comment: This is the fix for me, when you have scala cross-build.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. Solved it by completely deleting project, then clone it back from GIT.

Comment: This was the only thing that solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I solve in with 
Deletion both **gen** and **gen [generated]** from Source Folder.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by deleting .iml files of modules causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By deleting it in the module, and then importing it again. solve the problem.

I think it's a bug of IDEA.Eclipse is fine.

Hopefully idea developers will see that

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply renaming the project. Right click on the project, then click refactor.

Answer (score 0):

IN Intellij IDEA when you tap on parent module, in left pannel, make sure in right one, inside structures of child modules, folders are NOT marked as "Sources" and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

open:

file > project structure > modules
you will see 2 models

1. "project name"
2. "project name"_android

just delete "project name"_android in the module, that solved the problem for me.