# Intellij "java: package org.junit does not exist"

Tags: intellij-idea

When i try to run my test i get the following Errors:
I looked up on google and found somthing on google but this didn't help.

```
Error:(3, 24) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(3, 1) java: static import only from classes and interfaces
Error:(5, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(6, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(12, 10) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class Before
    location: class edu.kit.ipd.swt1.SimpleEditMeTest
Error:(17, 10) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class Test
    location: class edu.kit.ipd.swt1.SimpleEditMeTest
[...]
```

My test code:

```
package edu.kit.ipd.swt1;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleEditMeTest {
private EditMe editMe;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    editMe = new EditMe();
}
@Test
public void test() {
    assertNotNull(editMe.getFoo());
}
}
```

[Screenshot of the whole project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/754ND.png)

[Run configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WBMe.png)

Dependencies i.stack.imgur. com/OiQWU.png (Can't post more than 2 links)

Comment: Is junit declared as a test dependency in your pom.xml file?

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me:

1. Right click pom.xml
2. Select Maven
3. Reload project

Comment: Thanks! I had to close the project and reopen, IntelliJ synched all the dependences in the pom file.

Answer (score 21):

You are trying to run your test so you need to set the scope of JUnit to "compile" same as in the picture:

[image: 1]

Comment: What's the point of the `Test` scope if this is necessary?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem.  In order to fix it I had to Open Module Settings for my project and manually add jar Dependencies `junit-4.12.jar` and `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` which are contained in the IntelliJ installation lib directory.

Comment: I get `Failed to load plugin descriptor`

Comment: This failed for me I got "duplicate source error". My fix was to delete the duplicate source folder, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096434/249672

Comment: If you can run tests from IntelliJ but `org.junit.runner` can't be found. This solution solves it too.

Thanks!

Comment: Dont do it like this, please remove this answer. It only works on your local machine, but when you work with others on the same project it will not be fixed.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone ending up here using maven, a couple of things to check:

- (Sanity check) Have you added `junit` as a dependency in your pom.xml?
- Have Intellij accepted your module as a maven module? Try Right clicking the module/project and select `Add as Maven Project` or perhaps `Maven->Reimport`
- Are you using explicit version in your dependency declaration in your pom file? Like `<version>4.12</version>`. Try that. (You might not want to this because you want the version to be decided by a parent module. Read on.)
- Have you remembered to add a `dependencyManagement`? Maven need it to resolve the correct version number if you don't want to have it explicitly in the current project. For me it refers to the parent project. Like this:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${myproject.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: `Maven->Reimport` and then `Build->Rebuild` fixed it for me.

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaa, the simple things.  Yes, Going to the Maven dashboard (in intellij) and clicking re-import cleared the error.  There are several ways to do a dependency re-import for future readers.

Answer (score 6):

The solution to this is to add junit library as dependency to the project. This can be done by adding junit to global library and then hovering over the error(junit word) and right clicking to add junit to class path. 
alt+shift+ctrl+s to get project settings in the same either add junit to global library or to project section as mentioned by rob in his answer. [image: once you add it here the red bulb icon would give you option to resolve the error by adding it to class path.]

Comment: This fixed it for me, but I am curious why this is necessary. Why is it in `pom.xml` and do I need to add it as a global library too?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Adding JARs made no difference.  I solved it by adding library (not JAR) dependency for Junit 5.3

Answer (score 1):

You can go to project structure and edit dependencies by changing the junit dependency to compile from just test

[image: intelij community edition]

Answer (score 1):

Adding the JUnit dependency to build.gradle solved the issue

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I have also added `junit library dependency` manually to the project.

I'm using `IntelliJ 2020.2`

And it works !

[image: capture image adding junit library to intellij]

Answer (score 1):

I see this as a bug from intellij as they are not able to sometimes load the dependencies with the test scope during the build operations.
You can see that this error will only come for dependencies with the test scope.

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar problem that gave me headaches.
Then I noticed that I had some duplicates and the src/test folder added for Test Source Folders in Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules (only src/test/java should be added) :

[image: Modules sources roots]

So check your Modules sources roots.

Comment: This really helped. I was also getting compilation errors for the code in src/main/java. I tried the same suggestion for `Test Source folder` as well as the `Source folder`. Keeping only src/test/java in test source folders and src/main/java in source folder resolved both the compilation errors and junit jupter package does not exist error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupiter with Junit5 testing,
Then you need 2 things:
-> Jupiter-junit-api
-> Jupiter Engine

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while googling as I encountered this error when importing a legacy Gradle Java app into IntelliJ. None of the other answers solved my issue.

What I found was that IntelliJ was trying to import the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` folders as modules in the Project Wizard. When I deleted the recreated the IntelliJ project and *explicitly un-clicked the recommended modules*, the Gradle build worked successfully on the second run, since [the first build had a separate transient error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76902477/4851565).