# Cannot find IntelliJ IDEA project files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to build my project, but IntelliJ gives me this error:

```
Internal error (java.io.IOException): Cannot find IntelliJ IDEA project files at C:/Users/Alex/Documents/University/VII. Semestur/Ð•ÐŸ/Compiler_students_IntelliJ

at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:101)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:219)
```

I've checked all folders and cannot understand why these files are being labeled as missing.

Comment: I partially suspect the iffy encoding in folder name `/Ð•ÐŸ/`

Comment: Could you try renaming the folders without spaces or encoding

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. I've used Cyrillic letters and that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on seeing the folder name `Ð•ÐŸ`, rename the folders without spaces or encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question from a Google search. Note that my project didn't have any encoding or space issues as per the accepted answer - just an old legacy project that I was opening in IntelliJ. For me, the issue appears to have been something to do with initialization. Simply rebuilding the project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

check if you renamed the location of java projects
-open the pervious projects from your pc then take the location and enter it in the eclipse then open it

Comment: Problem was resolved soon after the question was posted (over a year ago). Did you not see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956907/cannot-find-intellij-idea-project-files#comment123680745_69956907) from the OP?